# Автоматическое выстраивание объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли возможность выстраивания элементов?
Допустим есть канвас, на котором стоят вряд кнопки.
Как сделать так, чтобы когда одна из кнопок скрывается, чтобы не оставалось пустого пространства от нее?

А когда снова показываем ее, чтобы она появлялась на том месте откуда скрыли.
Есть-ли, такая возможность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь в родительский объект (в инспекторе) [HorizontalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html)

При скрытии кнопки остальные будут растягиваться и чтобы этого не было на кнопки кинь (опять же в инспекторе) [LayoutElement](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html)